# about javascript extend function in book- [javascript-spessore]

Tags: javascript

I recently studying some books about javascript like javascript-spessore,
and I found some example codes snippet like extend is not built in javascript.
the code snippets is as following:

```
 var WidgetModel = function(id, attrs) {
   extend(this, attrs || {});
   this.id = function() {
     return id
   }
 }

  extend(WidgetModel.prototype, {
   set: function(attr, value) {
     this[attr] = value;
     return this;
   },
   get: function(attr) {
     return this[attr]
   }
 });
```

And of course, it not work and show an error message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: extend is not defined.
My problem is how to create a function like extend to make upper 
code snippet can work well. 
Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In supported environments, you could simply use...

```
let extend = Object.assign;
```

...or just use `Object.assign()` directly (this would be preferred).

If it's not supported, you could do it manually easily enough...

```
var extend = function(destination, source) {
    for (var prop in source) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)) {
            destination[prop] = source[prop];
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: @Ryan I was too lazy to write it, but you're right.

Comment: Why `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)` instead of `source.hasOwnProperty(prop)`? And why use a function expression instead of a function declaration?

Comment: @RobG For the case where the `source` object may have it defined directly on it (rare situation) and no real reason for function expression over declaration.

Comment: If someone replaces the built-in *hasOwnProperty* they deserve what they get. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```js
 var WidgetModel = function() {
 }

WidgetModel.prototype.name ='can';
WidgetModel.prototype.sayAge = function(age) {
 return age;
}

var model = new WidgetModel();

console.log(model.name);
console.log(model.sayAge(20));
```